# How to invoke the method myFunction to return (name) i've tried many ways but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Below is what am talking about

```
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    myFunction() {
        return function() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
let kk = new User("kk");
let speak = kk.myFunction();
speak();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: It is impossible to invoke `myFunction` to return the name as currently written.

Comment: The alert is after the return. That line will never run.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, what is it exactly that you're trying to do? If you want a new `User` then you should assign it to something `const jj = new User("jj");`. Then you can assign the function to something, `const speak = jj.myFunction()` and call it with `speak()`. Your function will return the name, but it won't alert as that is after your `return` statement

Comment: your function is returning a function right now... also, within your method `myFunction` scope, the reference to `name` would have to be bound to `this`, i.e. `this.name`. I think you would have to be more specific about your intent for this function in order to get a reasonable answer. because, I'm not sure why you would want to return a function unless that is your intent.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.name` instead, and the function should not return a function

```js
 class User {
   constructor(name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   myFunction() {
     alert(this.name);
     return this.name;
   }
}
let user = new User("jj").myFunction();

console.log(user)
```

EDIT:
The question you edited now is different from the original question you posted. This one needs a currying solution:

```js
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  myFunction() {
    let name = this.name;
    return function() {
      return name;
    }
  }
}
let kk = new User("kk");
let speak = kk.myFunction();
console.log(speak());
```

Comment: return is not a method

Comment: Thanks! I missed it.

Comment: yeah, but its still valid. he's not calling return as a method,... he's just referencing `this.name` as an expression and wrapping it in parens... its not nessesary but valid. @epascarello

Comment: @JaSuperior, it's not an error, it's just not the standard way of writing return statements.

Comment: what i wan't is to alert name

Comment: `name` is alerted indeed, but you have to call `alert` before the `return` statement as I did. In your code the function always terminates before it reaches the `alert` call.

Comment: Thanks the solution provided below works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [arrow function (`() => {}`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which won't have it's own binding of `this`, instead the `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used (your class in this case).

```js
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    myFunction() {
        return () => this.name;
    }
}
const speak = new User("kk").myFunction();
console.log(speak());
```